# Unactivated test phone?

Tags: iphone, testing

I have an iPhone 3G that I would like to use to test my app, however, it is not activated. Is it possible to use it as a test device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple won't let you get to the home screen without activation.

Your choices:

1. Buy a cheap prepaid AT&T SIM and activate with that (I think this should work, although I'm not entirely sure).
2. Jailbreak the iPhone to bypass activation.
3. Buy an iPod touch.

*Update*: your fourth choice is buying a full voice/data plan for the iPhone with AT&T. This is probably the easiest, and will give you a fully working iPhone, although it is expensive.

Comment: I don't think a prepaid AT&T SIM card would work... phones classified as smart phones have some kind of more complex activation process.

Comment: what exactly is activation? I assumed i had to go to ATT and get service for the phone.

Comment: @Earlz: As I remember, the original iPhone could be officially purchased with a prepaid plan if you didn't pass the credit check (some people entered zeroes for their SSN), and it would pass activation, so a prepaid card might work for the iPhone 3G. Again, though, I haven't tested any of this.

Comment: i already have an ATT plan with another phone, but I want to use the older phone to test how he app works.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be a problem. I use an old unactivated 3G to test my code on.

Comment: Sure it is not activated? It won't let you even visit the home screen without activation.

Comment: It was formerly activated, if that makes a difference. It's currently not activated.

Answer (score 0):

igul222 presented good options, but there is also something else you can do.

You could activate the iPhone with other AT&T card, and then switch it to not active AT&T card, and still it will work (except calls/sms). I work now in Europe with iPhone 3G that has not active At&T card in it from US and it works. Of course it has no service, so I can't call or text message, but you can test apps on it. I upgraded it to iOS4.0, it is connected to internet via WiFi  and I test apps on it.
So unless your application requires performing actual call you should be good. If it needs to perform call it will try but obviously fail due to now service.

One thing regarding 3G is that it doesn't want to run automated tests with Instruments. 3Gs with iOS4.0 works fine, but on 3G with iOS4.0 I get error message saying that this device is not supported.